# Visual Studio 2008 SP1 - Design View of page only shows the Master Page

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, master-pages

I'm creating a app that uses a Master Page.

But when i go to Design View of the page (for creating the events automatically or for drag/drop any new control from toolbox, I don't want to type everything) the design view only shows the master page! the page controls are complete ignored!

the image: http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/7980/masterissue.jpg

Does anybody know how to solve this issue??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it...
the problem is at the contentPaceHolder "Body" that has 2 other contentPlaceHolders inside, I think that I was thinking on doing nested master pages but forgot to do it in separate folders!

Answer (score 0):

Is it using a nested master page?
If you set the MasterPageFile="" (not remove the attribute, but set it to an empty string), can you then see the content page in Design View?
See the "Nesting Master Pages" section here: http://odetocode.com/code/450.aspx

Comment: its using only 1 master page for all app until now, I'm only coding the app, the nested master pages will be created after by the design people, I'm only using this master for not having to change each page title and include jquery scripts...